# How to make a value obtained from scanning a QR code into a string?

Tags: android

How do I make the value obtained from scanning a qr code and then put it into a string?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);
    fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
    fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
    btn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.scan));
    btn.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Comment: Which scanning library do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the ScanResultHandler you implement an interface, with a callback:

```
@Override
public void scanResult(ScanResult result) {

}
```

And there you have the result.

Comment: But how do i carry over the value (this) into another activity from the qr code scanner?

Comment: I think you need to add a few things to your question: your code and your intention.

Comment: I want to take the value which the qr code scanner get after scanner a qr code. Then carrying the value over into another activity.

Comment: So, basically passing data between activities? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: Yea but i can't get the value (which is 'this' in the code) into a string      .                                                  The line from the code :   fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);

Comment: As I said before, in the class you call the setScanResultHandler(this), you need to implement the interface accepted in the method call, I don't know the name of it. When you do that, you also need to implement the metods from the interface, and there you have your result, as I posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89228/discussion-between-tan-chong-kai-and-kenneth).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494654/how-to-take-the-qr-scanner-result-and-make-it-into-a-string/32494887#32494887  maybe it will be clearer on what i am asking