# How to take the QR scanner result and make it into a string?

Tags: android

How do I take the 'this' value ( from the 6th line) and make it into a string?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);
    fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
    fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
    btn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.scan));
    btn.setEnabled(false);

}
```

For example instead of just toasting the value, can I use the value and make it into a string and then carrying it into another activity.

```
@Override
public void scanResult(ScanResult result) {
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(QrscannerActivity.this,ProductInfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, result.getRawResult().getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Google ZXing Barcode Scanner** library and with the below code:

```
extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HandleClick hc = new HandleClick();
        findViewById(R.id.butQR).setOnClickListener(hc);
        findViewById(R.id.butProd).setOnClickListener(hc);
        findViewById(R.id.butOther).setOnClickListener(hc);
    }    
    private class HandleClick implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");     
        switch(arg0.getId()){
            case R.id.butQR:
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                break;
            case R.id.butProd:
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                break;
            case R.id.butOther:
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR");
                break;
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
        }
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            TextView tvStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
            TextView tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                tvStatus.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
                tvResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                tvStatus.setText("Press a button to start a scan.");
                tvResult.setText("Scan cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```